# Как правильно сделать фильтр товаров с чекбоксами model search?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет, не понимаю как правильно сделать фильтр товаров по свойствам. У меня yii2 advanced!
В фильтре хочу вывести хотя бы примитивное что бы понять как работает сам поиск.

Я вывел чекбоксы производителя и в адресной строки у меня

```
http://sportpit.alex-sport.com.ua/category/index?ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=62&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0&ProductPitSearch%5Bbrand_id%5D=0
```

ProductPitSearch

```
<?php

 namespace common\models;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;
 use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
 use common\models\ProductPit;

 /**
 * ProductPitSearch represents the model behind the search form about 
 `common\models\ProductPit`.
 */
 class ProductPitSearch extends ProductPit
 {
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'status', 'new', 'hit', 'sale', 'stock', 'top_sales', 'top_ten', 'category_id', 'img_id', 'gallery_id', 'brand_id', 'country_id', 'quantity', 'quantity_product', 'packing', 'availability', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['title', 'content', 'composition', 'vendor_code', 'seo_keywords', 'seo_description'], 'safe'],
        [['old_price', 'price'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = ProductPit::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'brand_id' => $this->brand_id,
        'country_id' => $this->country_id,
        'packing' => $this->packing,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'brand_id', $this->brand_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country_id', $this->country_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'packing', $this->packing]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

CategoryController

```
<?php

namespace sportpit\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\ProductPit;
use common\models\ProductPitSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
* CategoryController implements the CRUD actions for ProductPit model.
*/
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all ProductPit models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ProductPitSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Finds the ProductPit model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return ProductPit the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = ProductPit::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

_search

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\ProductPit;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\ProductPitSearch */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="product-pit-search">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>


<?php

$manufactures = ArrayHelper::map(ProductPit::find()->all(), 'brand_id', 'id');

foreach ($manufactures as $key => $value) {

    echo $form->field($model, 'brand_id')->checkbox(
        [
            'label' => ProductPit::getManufacturesTitle($value),
            'value' => $value
        ]
    );
    echo '<br/>';
}

?>

<?php // echo $form->field($model, 'country_id') ?>

<?php // echo $form->field($model, 'packing') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton(Yii::t('app', 'Reset'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

index

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel common\models\ProductPitSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Product Pits');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="product-pit-index">

<?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $this->render('_all', ['model' => $model]);
    },
]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

_all

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use common\models\ProductPit;
use common\models\CategoryPit;

?>

<div class="main_block">
<?php if ($model['hit']) : ?>
    <div class="hit_product label label-success">Хит</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($model['new']) : ?>
    <div class="new_product label label-primary">Новинка</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($model['sale']) : ?>
    <div class="sale_product label label-danger">Распродажа</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($model['stock']) : ?>
    <div class="sale_product label label-danger">Акция</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="image_block">
    <a href="<?= Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $model['id']]) ?>">
        <?php if ($model['img_id']) : ?>
            <?= Html::img('/web/uploads/products/' . ProductPit::getImageTitle($model['img_id']), ['width' => '105', 'height' => '150']) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?= Html::img('/web/uploads/system/no-image.png', ['width' => '105', 'height' => '150']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="title_block">
    <a href="<?= Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $model['id']]) ?>">
        <h1>
            <?= $model['title'] ?>
        </h1>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="category_block"><?= CategoryPit::getTitleCategory($model['category_id']) ?></div>
<div class="rating_block">*****</div>
<div class="price_block"><?= $model['price'] ?> грн.</div>
<div class="btn_buy_block">
    <a class="add-to-cart" data-id="<?= $model['id'] ?>"
       href="<?= Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $model['id']]) ?>">Купить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: а в чём вопрос то? не работает щас? Вся логика поиска пишется в файле ProductPitSearch

Comment: $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'brand_id', $this->brand_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country_id', $this->country_id]) это вообще не нужно

Comment: $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'brand_id', $this->brand_id]) ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country_id', $this->country_id]) вот это получается для input поля, я правильно понял???